# read and write mp3 binary file in c programing linux

Tags: c, linux, file, binary

is their any thing  I should consider while I am writing my program to get the write content of mp3 file and write to anenter code hereother file ? because am getting Error!

this is my code in c

```
FILE *fout;
fout = fopen("step.MP3","rb");
while (!feof(fout))
{
    fread(data,counter + 1,1,fout);
}
fclose(fout);


FILE  *fo;
fo = fopen("step.MP3", "wb");
fwrite(test,1,fileSize,fo);
fclose(fo);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and here's something that is able to solve your problem http://lame.sourceforge.net/index.php

Comment: `while (!feof(fout))`?  No, just no.  See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using an mp3 library to accomplish your task.  something like [lame](http://%20lame.sourceforge.net/index.php) or [Bass](http://www.un4seen.com/).  If you really want to do it yourself, read up on the mp3 file format: http://www.mp3-converter.com/mp3codec/mp3_anatomy.htm